# MYSQL 1 to N JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
tasks ( id int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, 
        description text, 
        created datetime, 
        modified datetime);

commentaries( id int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, 
              task_id int, 
              user_id int, 
              description text,
              created datetime );

users ( id int PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
        name varchar(300),
        created datetime );
```

It's One-To-Many relationship (1-N).

I'm building an inbox, to list the last N tasks, and to show the last inserted commentary for each task?

**EDIT1**:

The query:

```
SELECT T.id, T.description, C.description, T.created
FROM tasks T LEFT JOIN commentaries C ON T.id = C.task_id AND C.id IN (
                SELECT max(C.id) FROM tasks Task
                LEFT JOIN commentaries C ON C.task_id = Task.id
                WHERE Task.id in (select id from tasks WHERE user_id = 1 )
                GROUP BY Task.id)
ORDER BY T.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**EDIT2**

SQL Fiddle Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1555c7/1

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "Can you help" isn't a good question!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time of the last inserted commentary by using:

```
select task_id, max(created) as maxc
from commentaries
group by task_id;
```

You can get the last inserted commentary by using this in a `join`:

```
select t.*, c.*
from tasks t join
     commentaries c
     on c.task_id = t.id join
     (select task_id, max(created) as maxc
      from commentaries
      group by task_id
     ) cmax
     on cmax.task_id = c.task_id and cmax.maxc = c.created;
```

Comment: Thank you, i managed to get this working with your query, there's only a mistype on the last row, cmax.macc should be cmax.maxc

Comment: Using this query with a limit of 10 rows, it takes about 5 seconds, is there any faster way to get this query running?

Comment: Do you have the obvious indexes on the ids?

Comment: I've updated the question, you can check all the database structure plus SQL query on Fiddle

Comment: You can start by making your `id`s primary keys.

Comment: Done, but for a large as the table has more than 5000 commentaries, the query it's slow, the best solution i've found was to do a query to find the tasks and after iterate with PHP to find the last commentary for each task

Comment: @JohnSavimbi . . . I would also suggest an index on `commentaries(task_id, created)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.*, C.*
FROM tasks T
     JOIN Commentaries C
          ON T.id = C. task_id
GROUP BY T.id
ORDER BY C.task_id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This query it's not returning the last inserted commentary, but the first, how can i order it to get the last commentary?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know if i'm doing something wrong, but when a task as more than one commentary, it always return the first ( oldest ) one, instead of the last inserted ( for this task )

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from task,com   where task.id=com.task_id  order by com.da desc limit 1;
```